# JavaFX SubScene height sets to max height not to current height when resizing

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I have a SubScene placed in StackPane that I want to resize properly. Width resizing works perfect. However, height sets into the biggest value and does not shrink when the window is scaled down. How to force the height to keep the actual window height rather than the maximum one?

view.fxml:

```
<StackPane fx:id="MapPane"/>
```

Controller.java:

```
MapPane.getChildren().clear();
MapPane.getChildren().add(mapScene);
mapScene.setManaged(false);
                        mapScene.heightProperty().bind(MapPane.heightProperty());
mapScene.widthProperty().bind(MapPane.widthProperty());
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the subscene fxml code was preventing from shrinking the view in the `<BorderPane>` line.
Malfunctioning line:

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity">
```

Proper line:

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="0" minWidth="0">
```